# PayPal Error: encrypted_cross_dispatch

Tags: paypal

I have an issue with my e-commerce site. Every time a customer tries to make payment, we get an error :

```
encrypted_cross_dispatch=0XxmEYQZCCvvS9xFhmAlcOBNRPWGtQd5vrH0ObYXID8wQo7jLtJPeo3yqJRFbkScZWXT5zvvamAy6LND4uHFLR4ohRrSkE3E9_6T0G
```

This was working well till 24hrs ago.

Issue only on WordPress Sites.

Anybody has an idea if this a problem with PayPal systems or API issue?
[See Error in the image below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqxwY.jpg)

Comment: I tried doing the payment with Sandbox testing account and it is working fine. Please try using Paypal again as the server may be down.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are using the incorrect URL for web payments. Your picture shows ipnpb.paypal.com as browser location, but this URL is only for IPN (Instant Payment Notification) validation postbacks, so should not be in the browser. So probably you're using that URL in the payment button form, can you check the config of your e-commerce site?

The correct URL for PayPal payment button forms should be:

- Sandbox: https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
- Live: https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr

We had the same problem, using the IPN url worked until recently, PayPal must have changed something internally so now it breaks.